# can't figure out a loop with some conditions

Tags: python

I'm starting to learn programming and trying to write my first flash game bot, but I think I can't sort things out

This game is, player click in 5 areas randomly, if player is lucky, the enemy will get shot and reduce his hp. Enemy's hp is 6, and this game requires player to finish this in no more than 7 shots, which means player has only one chance to miss the guess.

So I "cut" the HP bar into 6 jugdement areas, and use PIL in python to judge the pixel's color change in every area, then let pyautogui to do some auto clicks. Main part of this code is:

```
while True:
    flag = 1
    for i in range(6):
        s = screenGrab()
        pixels = s.load()
        pixelJugde_1 = pixels[judgeAreas[i]] # jugde if hp is reduced after this shot
        if pixelJugde_1 != (0, 0, 0): # if this shot missed
            randomClick() # try again
            s = screenGrab()
            pixels = s.load()
            pixelJugde_2 = pixels[judgeAreas[i]] # second judge of this shot
            if (pixelJugde_2 != pixelJugde_1): # hp changed, second try didn't miss
                flag = 1  # mark this shot has been tried twice
                randomClick() # continue next shot
            elif (pixelJugde_2 == pixelJugde_1 and flag == 1): # second try missed
                resetResult() # restart the game
                break
        else:
            print 'got shot' # success at first try
            randomClick() # next shot
```

now my problem is, if the first shot has been tried twice and marked, when the next shot begins and misses, it will still try twice, just like the marking flag is not working. So how to fix this?

Comment: Under what conditions is `flag!=1`? You're never setting it to anything else...  A 1 indicates it fired twice? Why not a 2?

Comment: yes `flag = 1` means fired twice, so what should do to let the loop know that one shot only fired once?

Comment: Why do you set that before the loop? Before any shots are fired?